# Keras: flow_from_directory saving too many images during fit_generator call

Tags: keras, generator

I have the following train/validation code:

```python
# we create two instances with the same arguments
image_data_gen_args         = dict(rotation_range=90.0, rescale=1/255.0)
mask_data_gen_args          = dict(rotation_range=90.0, rescale=1/255.0)
train_image_datagen         = ImageDataGenerator(**image_data_gen_args)
train_mask_datagen          = ImageDataGenerator(**mask_data_gen_args)
validation_image_datagen    = ImageDataGenerator()
validation_mask_datagen     = ImageDataGenerator(**mask_data_gen_args)

# Provide the same seed flow methods
seed = 1

train_image_generator = train_image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    abs_parent_train_images_path,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed,
    follow_links=True, # we symlinked the images to a temp directory
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size))

train_mask_generator = train_mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    abs_parent_train_masks_path,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed,
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    color_mode="grayscale",
    save_to_dir=abs_parent_train_masks_path)

validation_image_generator = validation_image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    abs_parent_test_images_path,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed,
    follow_links=True,  # we symlinked the images to a temp directory
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size))

validation_mask_generator = validation_mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    abs_parent_test_masks_path,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed,
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    color_mode="grayscale",
    save_to_dir=abs_parent_test_masks_path)

# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator         = itertools.izip(train_image_generator, train_mask_generator)
validation_generator    = itertools.izip(validation_image_generator, validation_mask_generator)

# test generators' saving
for idx, pair in enumerate(validation_generator):
    print(idx)
    print('iterating')
    if idx >= 0:
        break

modeler.model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                            steps_per_epoch=1,
                            validation_data=validation_generator,
                            validation_steps=1,
                            epochs=1,
                            callbacks=callbacks_list,
                            verbose=1)
```

The four train/validation directories either have 1 image or mask in the required `directory/subdirectory/image` organization for `flow_from_directory`.  So directory structure is believed not to be the issue.  This further confirmed by kera's printouts during training:

```python
Found 1 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 1 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 1 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 1 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

I've noticed that `fit_generator` saves more than one image per train run.
Since, **epochs, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps and number of images/masks (for train/validation) all equal 1**, I would have expected exactly **one** image to be saved during the call to `fit_generator`.  However, the number seems to be **9** (same image but each possessing a different rotation).

Interestingly this seems to be a result of `fit_generator` and not the `ImageDataGenerator` class, since I can breakpoint just after the `for` loop iterating over `validation_generator` and find exactly one image saved per iteration of the `for` loop (as expected).

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?
Is this expected behavior (and why)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fit_generator` function has two additional parameters that are probably the cause of the observed behavior:

- `workers` with default value `=1` means that an extra thread will be used to load the images. The thread will fetch the images from the provided generator and put them into a queue.
- `max_queue_size` with default value `=10` is the maximum length of this queue. The enqueuer thread will be stopped when the call to `fit_generator` returns, but before it will continue to fill the queue up with images, even if some of those won't be needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks!  Adding `workers=0` to both `fit_generator` and `evaluate_generator` reduces the number of saved images in each call respectively to 1.